# Pandas dataframe: representing variable length 3D data? column with variable length list?

Tags: python, pandas

There's been a couple times where I've had a timeseries, where one of the columns is a variable length array of information.

One example would be image statistics, where the index is a datetime, and the columns are statistics.  There is also some global information for each image (location, size, average intensity, etc), but also a variable number of features are detected, and is some information for each of those features (e.g. response, distance, angle).

I'd want to be able to plot and explore both global frame stats along with the feature stats.  For example, plotting average intensity vs location.  However, I'd also want to be able to do histograms or violin plots across all of the features: e.g. density plots of feature responses based on time of day.  Idealy I could groupby and have all of those variable length lists (feature responses) appended to the same group.

I'd love to be able to represent as much as I can natively pandas. Of course I could have a tuple or np.array, and groupby manually, but then I couldn't serialize to a table format, unless I convert to a string, etc.

Comment: did you consider using HDF?  It ties in well with numpy and pandas, allows you to have a bunch of attributes that describe the timeseries and has 2 good python modules H5PY and PyTables.

Comment: Can you explain how to tie it in with reference to my question? I use HDF to store the entire dataframe (in fixed format, not table format), but are you saying I can reference a HDF as a column for a row?